# Angularjs Image Upload showing empty nested object

Tags: php, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, laravel-5

I'm a bit confused how to access file data using with angular from a basic form. I'm following a tut on: (https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) and youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLHgpOG1cW4). They seem to get it right but when I try things seem to go a different way. Anyways here's my HTML form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="customer.email" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">Image</label>
        <input type="file" file-model="customer.file" id="file" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the Directive

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And finally the controller:

```
app.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope','CustomerService', function($scope, CustomerService){
    $scope.customer = {};
    CustomerService.save($scope.customer);
}]);
```

When I `{{ customer }}` in my view I'm getting something like this:

```
{"name":"Robert DeNiro","email":"robie@godfather.com","file":{}}
```

It's that empty last `"file":{}` file object that's causing me problems getting values to post to server.

Here's my Customer Service code:

```
var CustomerService = function($resource) {

        return $resource('advertisements/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
              },
        save: {
            method: 'post',
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    });
    };

    CustomerService.$inject = ['$resource'];
    app.service('CustomerService', CustomerService);
```

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and its reporting validation errors 'required' on all fields suggesting there's an empty object sent through. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a `submit()` method in `CustomerController` like this:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    var file = $scope.customer.file;
    console.log('file is ' );
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log($scope.customer.file);
    console.dir($scope.customer.file);
};
```

And in there you can see I've tried experimenting with `console.log()` and `console.dir()` and i seem to get the results. For example if i `console.log($scope.customer)` or `console.dir($scope.customer)` it gives me the nested file object with all file details. And its looking like this:

```
> Object {name: "robert deniro", email: "robie@godfather.com", file: File}
> Object
```

Notice `file: File` Therefore I'm able to access the file contents/object within the `submit()` like this: `console.log(file.name)` or `console.log(file.type)` or `console.log(file.size)`. I don't know why I was missing it all this time. I hope someone learn from my mistake.

Comment: it looks silly but it really works. I don't know why we have to apply var file = $scope.file; but it works. Any ideas why we have to assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

May be that form requires the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but same problem.